# how to convert an HTML class to visual force component class

Tags: visualforce-component, class, html5, inputtext

I have a code in HTML and i need to convert it into VF.

My HTML code is like

```
    <input  id="Lname" value="" class="validate[required] text-input" maxlength="40" name="LastName_Web__c" size="20" type="text"/>

My apex code is like

    <apex:outputLabel for="Fname" >NOMBRE* </apex:outputLabel>

            <apex:inputText id="Fname" value="{!sFirstname }" onblur="validate(required)"  maxlength="20"/>


     (function($) {
    $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function() {};
    $.validationEngineLanguage = {
        newLang: function() {
            $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules =   {"required":{               // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an example
                        "regex":"none",
                        "alertText":"*Champ obligatoire",
                        "alertTextCheckboxMultiple":"* Please select an option",
                        "alertTextCheckboxe":"* This checkbox is required"},
                    "telephone":{
                        "regex":"/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]+$/",
                        "alertText":"*Numéro de téléphone incorrect"},  

                    "mobile":{
                        "regex":"/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]+$/",
                        "alertText":"*Numéro de mobile incorrect"},

                    "email":{
                        "regex":"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+[\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/",
                        "alertText":"*Adresse e-mail incorrecte"},  
}
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Please let me know how to declare a HTML class in VF component.

Comment: To reference a CSS class it's the `styleClass` attribute - see documentation such as [apex:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm).

Comment: its not a CSS class , it s a function .. any idea how to call it !

Comment: The HTML code you've posted does not contain any functions.

Comment: added the function

Comment: If I understand how tools like jQuery.validationEngine work, the CSS is consumed by the JavaScript. So `styleClass="validate[required] text-input"` would be my first guess of what you need.

Comment: @KeithC I have tried the same, but it seems not to pick up my class. Any other suggestions ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript you posted reports errors in http://jshint.com/ as it is missing a `}` towards the end. This does not report errors there; try it:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function() {};
    $.validationEngineLanguage = {
        newLang: function() {
            $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {
                "required": { // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an example
                    "regex": "none",
                    "alertText": "*Champ obligatoire",
                    "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Please select an option",
                    "alertTextCheckboxe": "* This checkbox is required"
                },
                "telephone": {
                    "regex": "/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]+$/",
                    "alertText": "*Numéro de téléphone incorrect"
                },

                "mobile": {
                    "regex": "/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]+$/",
                    "alertText": "*Numéro de mobile incorrect"
                },

                "email": {
                    "regex": "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)+[\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/",
                    "alertText": "*Adresse e-mail incorrecte"
                },
            };
        }
    };
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

Always check your browser's JavaScript console for errors (and you can output debug information to it).

Comment: It's also good practice to add "use strict" first thing inside your closure.

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, I'm sorry I didn’t understand.  What's "use strict"?

Comment: It really [is not hard to search](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+use+strict&oq=javascript+use+strict&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2880j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).